# ListViewItem is grayed out

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, android-listview

i am currently programming an app in android. In this app i´ve got a ListActivity with a ListView in it. I wanted this ListView to have custom items so i wrote a custom BaseAdapter in which i specify my items. That works fine so far.
Here´s the XML-code for the ListActivity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PalettenActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewPaletten"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@layout/paletten_item"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I also wrote a XML-file for the item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layoutPalettenItem"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:context=".PalettenAdapter" >
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewPalettenBez"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="Bezeichnung"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPalettenPlus"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="+"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewPalettenAnzahl"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/buttonPalettenPlus"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonPalettenPlus"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonPalettenPlus"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPalettenMinus"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textViewPalettenAnzahl"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewPalettenAnzahl"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textViewPalettenAnzahl"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now the problem i am facing is that the ListItem is grayed out in the ListView so i cant press any buttons.
As you can see i tried `android:focusable="false"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` on the item and `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on the ListView. But nothing changes at all.

This is how it looks:
[image: ListView with grayed out item]
As you can see the Button on the bottom looks normal but all Views of the item are grayed out.

Here`s the code of my onCreate() of my ListActivity:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
dataSource = new DataSource(this);

int id_lieferschein = getID_Lieferschein();
if (id_lieferschein > 0) {
  paletten = ladePaletten(id_lieferschein);
  /*"ladePaletten()" extracts data form a SQLite-DB and stores it into a 
  ArrayList called "paletten". */
  if (paletten != null && paletten.size() > 0) {
    adapter = new PalettenAdapter(this, paletten);  // my BaseAdapter
    listViewPaletten = getListView();
    listViewPaletten.setAdapter(adapter);
    listViewPaletten.setEnabled(true);
  }
}
```

And here`s the getView() of my BaseAdapter:

```
try {
    LayoutInflater itemInflater =(LayoutInflater)parent.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
/* "parent" is my ListActivity. It`s a private variable of my BaseAdapter. I hand it over in the constructor of this class */
            if (convertView == null) 
                convertView = itemInflater.inflate(R.layout.paletten_item, null);   
            
            convertView.setMinimumHeight(120);
            convertView.setEnabled(true);
            
            ladePalette(convertView, paletten.get(position), position); 
            /* in "ladePaletten()" i attach some onClickListeners to some 
            buttons of the ListView-Item. */
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
return convertView;
```

I´d be glad if someone could help me with this issue. .
Thanks for your help!
Morris F.

Comment: please add code for listactivity and baseAdapter.

Comment: Just did so.
Tell me if you need more info

Answer (score 0):

In your XML file you written **enteries** attribute. So, please remove that because, you are adding values by adapter and also xml through(By the way, you are adding layout not array). Both are conflicting therefore, you don't need to write in xml in **Listview**.

**Instead of,**

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewPaletten"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@layout/paletten_item"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" >
</ListView>
```

**To,**

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewPaletten"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" >
</ListView>
```

Also, I have attached example of Custom Listview.

**1) activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="#FF9D9D"
     tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ListView
     android:id="@+id/listViewPaletten"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**2) Paletten_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layoutPalettenItem"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewPalettenBez"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:text="Bezeichnung"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonPalettenPlus"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="+"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewPalettenAnzahl"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/buttonPalettenPlus"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonPalettenPlus"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonPalettenPlus"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonPalettenMinus"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textViewPalettenAnzahl"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewPalettenAnzahl"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textViewPalettenAnzahl"
    android:text="-"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**3) MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;

private String[] names ={
        "Item1",
        "Item2",
        "Item3",
        "Item4",
        "Item5"
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = findViewById(R.id.listViewPaletten);
    listView.setAdapter(new ListviewAdapter(names,getApplicationContext()));

}
}
```

**4) ListviewAdapter.java**

```
public class ListviewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private String[] names;
Context context;

public ListviewAdapter(String[] names, Context context) {
    this.names = names;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return names.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.paletten_item,parent,false);

        TextView tv_names = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPalettenBez);
        tv_names.setText(names[position]);
    }
    return convertView;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! 
My MainActivity now extends Activity and no longer ListActivity, I've deleted `android:entries="@layout/paletten_item"` from my XML, I do `setContentView(R.layout.activity_paletten);` and
`adapter = new PalettenAdapter(this, paletten);  // paletten is a ArrayList`
`listViewPaletten = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewPaletten);`
`listViewPaletten.setAdapter(adapter);`
`listViewPaletten.setEnabled(true);`
in `my onCreate()` but nothing changes. All the items say gray.